# How to handle data errors during Sqoop export and import

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

If there are any data issues in the source database like 
- when a number field has character or 
- date field is not populated properly,

Is there any way to handle these exceptions and continue with the remaining records in sqoop without failing the job?

I could see that there is similar question below asked few years back but it is unanswered.
[Handling bad records during sqoop import or export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18446911/handling-bad-records-during-sqoop-import-or-export)

Would like know if there is any option in the latest version of Sqoop.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, this problem is not solved at this time. A Jira has been opened last year in order to find a solution. But for the moment, you can't handle  bad records by skipping its.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-1856

However, it is possible to handle bad records by modifing data during sqoop import with a free-form query. check the following sqoop arguments:

```
--query and --split-by
```

Here is a good tutorial from sqoop cookbook concerning free-form queries:

https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/apache-sqoop-cookbook/9781449364618/ch04.html